# Files not being committed by Git

Tags: git

Here is what I did:

- Modified some files in my repo and branch
- Pulled and merged master into my branch

Now, Git shows that a bunch of files have been modified but I can't seem to commit them.

```
~/project (my-branch) $ git status
On branch my-branch
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   admin_cmds/admin.py
    modified:   admin_cmds/promotions/forms.py
    ...
```

I have tried:

```
git add .
git commit
```

And also:

```
git commit -a
```

Not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: You'll have to give a bit more details. What did you get when you tried to add/commit? What does `git status` output at this point? Following what you describe, at this point you should have a clean working tree and a new commit showing up on `git log`

Comment: Or the status after `git add admin_cmds/admin.py` ?

Comment: Yeah, good point Steve, first make sure you're adding from the root of your repo or the `.` might capture nothing and you're adding nothing.

Comment: Use `git add -A` so you're staging the whole repo even if you're not at repo root.